# Flutter with riverpod and isar notifier hangup

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-isar

While trying to update an isar database using riverpod, my app hangs up.  Here is the flutter line where it hangs:

```dart
ref.read(todosProvider.notifier).updateTodo(
                              id,
                              editedDescription: editedDescription,
                              editedTaskGroup: editedTaskGroup,
                              editedTaskDueDate: editedTaskDueDate,
                              creationDate: creationDate,
                                );
```

Here is the error from the hover error window:

```
_origin:
<error: org-dartlang-debug:synthetic_debug_expression:1:1: Error: The getter '_origin' isn't defined for the class 'StateNotifierProvider<NotifierT, T>'.
 - 'StateNotifierProvider' is from 'package:riverpod/src/state_notifier_provider.dart' ('../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod-2.3.10/lib/src/state_notifier_provider.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named '_origin'.
_origin
^^^^^^^>
_override:
<error: org-dartlang-debug:synthetic_debug_expression:1:1: Error: The getter '_override' isn't defined for the class 'StateNotifierProvider<NotifierT, T>'.
```

I've looked at the providers and implementations for writing to the isar db but have not found anything yet.  If anyone can suggest places to look for the correction, it would be appreciated.